# How do I optimise this mysql query?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT MAX( CAST( auction_price.Auctionprice AS SIGNED ) ) AS `max_auction_price`
FROM auction_detail
LEFT JOIN auction_price ON auction_detail.auction_id = auction_price.auction_id
WHERE auction_detail.season = '2011'
AND auction_detail.sale_no = '26'
AND auction_detail.area LIKE '%Mumbai%'
AND auction_detail.broker_code LIKE '%PAP%'
AND auction_detail.category LIKE '%CTC%'
AND auction_detail.tea_type LIKE '%BEST%'
```

The above query takes about 49secs to run, so I really need to optimize it for performance. Any suggestions?

Comment: How fast does it execute without the JOIN? Try commenting them out and fetch a value from auction_detail instead to determine if the WHERE-part is the slow part.

Comment: What is the type of `auction_price.Auctionprice`?

Comment: `EXPLAIN` is your friend (See answer below by @bigkm). http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html Run the query with explain and post the results here. People will be able to give you a more in-depth answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run the command in mysql prefixed with explain, it will show you what indexes are being used in the query, it'll take a bit to learn how to read the output but it's not too hard.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT MAX( CAST( auction_price.Auctionprice AS SIGNED ) ) AS `max_auction_price`
FROM auction_detail
LEFT JOIN auction_price ON auction_detail.auction_id = auction_price.auction_id
WHERE auction_detail.season = '2011'
AND auction_detail.sale_no = '26'
AND auction_detail.area LIKE '%Mumbai%'
AND auction_detail.broker_code LIKE '%PAP%'
AND auction_detail.category LIKE '%CTC%'
AND auction_detail.tea_type LIKE '%BEST%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the LIKE keywords words that always stand on their own (as opposed to parts of strings)? (`Mumbai`, `PAP`, `CTC`, `BEST`)

If so, give [full-text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) a try. A properly indexed full-text search might be faster than LIKEs.

Answer (score 0):

Create indexes.

for example

- on `auction_detail.sale_no` and on `auction_price.auction_id`.

OR

- on `auction_detail.area` and on `auction_price.auction_id` and query
  like `'Mumbai%'` (that is, without %)

Answer (score 0):

- There is no point to use **LEFT** join in this particular case. Use **INNER** join;
- Create a **composite** index (`sale_no, season`).